# How to backup from .mdf database that created by VS

Tags: c#, backup, sql-server-express

I was created a .mdf database file with vs 2010. I can retrive and insert data into database bbut when i want to backup error was handled. that database not attach in Management Studio.

my Code :

```
SqlConnection connect;
connect = new SqlConnection(DAL.AccessLayerClass._connectionStr);
connect.Open();
SqlCommand command;
command = new SqlCommand(@"backup database AGMDB to disk ='d:\svBackUp1.bak' with init,stats=10",connect);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connect.Close();
MessageBox.Show("The support of the database was successfully performed", "Back", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

my connection string:

```
string _connectionStr = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=" + System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\Database\\AGMDB.mdf; Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=30; User Instance=True;";
```

and that error was occurs:

```
Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'AGMDB'. No entry found with that name. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

how can i solve this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `[]` around DBFileName, try this:

```
SqlConnection connect;
connect = new SqlConnection(DAL.AccessLayerClass._connectionStr);
connect.Open();
SqlCommand command;
command = new SqlCommand(@"backup database [" + System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\Database\\AGMDB.mdf] to disk ='d:\svBackUp1.bak' with init,stats=10",connect);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connect.Close();
MessageBox.Show("The support of the database was successfully performed", "Back", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Reference : [How to Backup and Restore SQL Express 2005 (AttachDbFilename mode)](http://weblogs.asp.net/morteza/archive/2009/10/08/how-to-backup-and-restore-sql-express-2005-attachdbfilename-mode.aspx)

Comment: Don't beg for up votes. Also, simply posting little more than a link doesn't make a good answer, check this FAQ entry for guidance: [How do I write a good answer to a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question). And square brackets around identifiers are not mandatory unless it is to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: No problems, if you fix up your answer a bit, maybe add an excerpt from the page you linked to then I will cancel my down vote.